# Meteor loses login session on page change (heroku only)

Tags: javascript, session, backbone.js, heroku, meteor

I have a meteor app with backbone routing.  When running locally, I can browse to different pages and the currentUser stays logged in.  When I run it on heroku (I also tried appfog with the same results)  once I browse to a different page, it loses the currentUser session.

I'm running meteor version 0.6.4.1

I used this buildpack for heroku:
https://github.com/v8squirrel/heroku-buildpack-meteor

And demeteorizer for app fog:
https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: I was able to repeat this using the example [meteor parties](http://whispering-springs-9172.herokuapp.com) app. Just create a login(can use fake@fake.com | fakefake), refresh the page a couple times, and note that on occasion the app will not login properly.  It only seems to be happening on chrome and I'm on mac osx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a meteor/chrome bug and will be fixed in version 0.6.5.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1244

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/Pct1_kFlp4I/3a2lXlyF6zcJ